# Ruby when to use <% or <%= for opening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Sorry I'm very new to Ruby and this is probably a simple question and I am just searching wrong for it.
For example:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
<% end %>
```

Why do we only use <% %> at the beginning and end of the loop, but <%= is used in the loop?

Another example, no loop involved:

```
<li><%= link_to "Contact Us", new_contact_path %></li>
```

Why am I using <%= instead of <% here?
Thanks for helping me with this newb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use `<%=` when you want the ERB to actually render code as a string in the browser, and `<%` when you simply want to execute Ruby code (e.g. performing an iteration, setting a variable, etc.)

In your examples:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
<% end %>
```

`<%` is used on `flash.each` to iterate over the `flash` variable, and then `<%=` is used to actually render a `content_tag` containing the values set when piping in `key` and `value` into the block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using erb?

<%> will execute the ruby code inside the brackets

<%=> will actually render some code in your view